# can anyone tell me how to create RESTful web services in spring with annotations

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am new to spring RESTful web services. can anyone tell me how to create RESTful web services in spring with annotations and what all jars to be included in the project? also how do i test it whether my web service is working fine. do we have a small demo example which serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/ is a very good and useful tutorial. It goes through how to set up the Spring MVC project from scratch using Maven as your build tool and then it goes through a Spring MVC controller that uses the URL to perform REStful Web Services. Although it may seem small, the tutorial is very useful in getting you started and provides you with a platform to carry out more complex tasks. The following reference may be useful as a reference. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

Comment: Please link to the latest version of the Spring documentation. Did you get that link by searching for `spring rest annotations`? :-)